# Input String is not in Correct Format when reading DataTable values

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am performing sum of two columns using DataTable, first time converts and perform addition but second time it is giving me Input string is not in correct format
My code is here:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("BillingAmount")
dt.Columns.Add("RecievedAmount")
dt.Columns.Add("Balance")

For i As Integer = 0 To mstr_DataTable.Rows.Count - 1
   Dim BillingAmount As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(drw("BillingAmount").ToString()) + Decimal.Parse(mstr_DataTable.Rows(0)("BillAmount").ToString()) 
   '^ I am getting exception here .
   drw("BillingAmount") = BillingAmount.ToString()
   drw("RecievedAmount") = mstr_DataTable.Rows(0)("PaymentAmount").ToString()
   Dim Balance As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(drw("BillingAmount").ToString()) - Decimal.Parse(mstr_DataTable.Rows(0)("PaymentAmount").ToString())
   '^ I am getting exception here .
   drw("Balance") = Balance.ToString()
Next
```

Comment: You code seems to be VB.Net

Comment: What are the values of `mstr_DataTable.Rows(0)("BillAmount")` and `drw("BillingAmount")` and the rests? Do you see them in your debugger?

Comment: Please post your exception details also.

Comment: Why are you converting the values of `BillAmount` etc to strings and then parse them? If they were decimals/doubles already, you'd only have to add the values (if you used `drw.BillingAmount`) or at most, cast them to their actual type

Comment: Use the debugger. See what the value is. Is it a number?